# getting cmake to build an external dependency requiring configure && make && make install

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I'd like to build `ta-lib` via `cmake`'s `fetchcontent` function in my

##### `CMakeLists.txt`

```
FetchContent_Declare(ta_lib
        DOWNLOAD_DIR /tmp
        URL http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND configure
        BUILD_COMMAND make
        INSTALL_COMMAND "make install"
        )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ta_lib)
include_directories(${ta_lib_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ta_lib)
```

I checked that the script above is able to download and decompress the tar-ball, and populate `cmake-build-release/_deps/ta_lib-src` with the project source, but it fails to build via the desired `configure && make && make install` sequence. The cmake build doesn't complain, proceeding normally as in the headers are found, but ultimately fails with `-lta_lib not found`.

I tried `BUILD_IN_SOURCE TRUE` as well, however I get the error

```
External project ta_lib-populate has both BINARY_DIR and BUILD_IN_SOURCE!
```

How does one get the build and install step to actually kick in?

Comment: "I checked that the script above is able to download and decompress the tar-ball, and populate `cmake-build-release/_deps/ta_lib-src` with the project source" - So, this is the **ultimate purpose** of `FetchContent_Declare`: populate the source tree. The function `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` will make that source tree to be part of main project's sources. CONFIGURE and all further commands has no sense for the `FetchContent_Declare`. [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_declare) explicitly notes, that these commands are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly missing a few things.

- Your `make install` command most likely is trying to `install` to the default path, and that's not what you want. You need to add a prefix, `./configure --prefix <path>`, and make it so that it's local to your project, e.g., `tmp/`, that you can find it later.
- One you have that, you need identify where `ta_lib` is installed and links it manually using the `target_link_libraries`. Here, you most likely cannot just use `ta_lib` because it's surely not defined. You need to find the path to the library, if needed. Check your `tmp/` folder for a clue, and consult the [`FetchContent`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/module/FetchContent.html) documentation.

Unfortunately, I cannot think of a good example on the top of my head to add here.